# Crear base de datos MySQL desde script en bash ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, bash, script

Quisiera crear una base de datos mediante un script que ya tengo, en MySQL desde la bash de ubuntu 16.04, el script es el siguiente

```
-- Creamos la tabla si esta no existe
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS platzi;

-- Indicamos que trabajaremos sobre la tabla 
-- recien creada
USE platzi;

-- Declaramos las tablas de nuestra DB
CREATE TABLE books (
book_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
publisher_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
description TEXT,
price DECIMAL(5,2),
copies INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE publishers (
publisher_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
email varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE actions (
action_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
book_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
action_type ENUM('venta','prestamo','devolucion') NOT NULL,
created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

-- datos 

INSERT INTO users(name, email) VALUES
('Ricardo', 'ricardo@hola.com'),
('Laura', 'laura@hola.com'),
('Jose', 'jose@hola.com'),
('Sofia', 'sofia@hola.com'),
('Fernanda', 'fernanda@hola.com'),
('Jose Guillermo', 'memo@hola.com'),
('Maria', 'Maria@hola.com'),
('Susana', 'susana@hola.com'),
('Jorge', 'jorge@hola.com');

INSERT INTO publishers(publisher_id, name, country) VALUES
(1, 'OReilly', 'USA'),
(2, 'Santillana', 'Mexico'),
(3, 'MIT Edu', 'USA'),
(4, 'UTPC', 'Colombia'),
(5, 'Platzi', 'USA');

INSERT INTO books(publisher_id, title, author, description, price, copies) VALUES
(1, 'Mastering MySQL', 'John Goodman', 'Clases de bases de datos usando MySQL', 10.50, 4),
(2, 'Trigonometria avanzada', 'Pi Tagoras', 'Trigonometria desde sus origenes', 7.30, 2),
(3, 'Advanced Statistics', 'Carl Gauss', 'De curvas y otras graficas', 23.60, 1),
(4, 'Redes Avanzadas', 'Tim Berners-Lee', 'Lo que viene siendo el internet', 13.50, 4),
(2, 'Curvas Parabolicas', 'Napoleon TNT', 'Historia de la parabola', 6.99, 10),
(1, 'Ruby On (the) Road', 'A Miner', 'Un nuevo acercamiento a la programacion', 18.75, 4),
(1, 'Estudios basicos de estudios', 'John Goodman', 'Clases de bases de datos usando MySQL', 10.50, 4),
(4, 'Donde esta Y?', 'John Goodman', 'Clases de bases de datos usando MySQL', 10.50, 4),
(3, 'Quimica avanzada', 'John White', 'Profitable studies on chemistry', 45.35, 1),
(4, 'Graficas Matematicas', 'Rene Descartes', 'De donde viene el plano', 13.99, 7),
(4, 'Numeros Importantes', 'Leonhard Euler', 'De numeros que a veces nos sirven', 10, 3),
(3, 'Modelado de conocimiento', 'Jack Friedman', 'Una vez adquirido, como se guarda el conocimiento', 29.99, 2),
(3, 'Teoria de juegos', 'John Nash', 'A o B?', 12.55, 3),
(1, 'Calculo de variables', 'Brian Kernhigan', 'Programacion mega basica', 9.50, 3),
(5, 'Produccion de streaming', 'Juan Pablo Rojas', 'De la oficina a la pantalla', 23.49, 9),
(5, 'ELearning', 'JFD & CvdH', 'Diseno y ejecucion de educacion online', 23.55, 4),
(5, 'Pet Caring for Geeks', 'KC', 'Que tu perro aprenda a programar', 18.79, 3),
(1, 'Algebra basica', 'Al Juarismi', 'Eso de encontrar X o Y, dependiendo', 13.50, 8);

INSERT INTO actions(book_id, user_id, action_type) VALUES
(3, 2, 'venta'),
(6, 1, 'prestamo'),
(7, 7, 'prestamo'),
(7, 7, 'devolucion'),
(2, 5, 'venta'),
(10, 9, 'venta'),
(18, 8, 'prestamo'),
(12, 4, 'venta'),
(1, 3, 'venta'),
(4, 5, 'prestamo'),
(5, 2, 'venta');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo las credenciales de la base de datos, por ende tienes instalado mysql-server y mysql-client ademas suponiendo que tu script se llama script.sql y estas parado en el directorio deberias ejecutar algo como :

```
mysql -u usuario -p < script.sql
```

Luego de eso te pedira la clave del usuario que estas usando para la base de datos. Mas información en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html